# Swap list of tuples in Python with multiple elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I am trying to swap the cities and their respective locations in the list of tuples:

```
my_cities = [("London", "Rome", 38.197274, -84.86311),
                ("Michigan", "Denver", 39.161921, -75.526755),
                ("Paris", "Lisbon", 44.95, -93.094)]
```

so every city gets a new pair, so the output should be a list of tuples with the new city pairs + their locations.

I've tried:

```
def swap_cities(my_cities):
    for x in range(0, len(my_cities) - 1): 
        my_cities[x] = (my_cities[x+1][0], my_cities[x+1][0])

        return my_cities
```

But it doesn't give me the right result:

```
[('Michigan', 'Michigan'),
 ('Michigan', 'Denver', 39.161921, -75.526755),
 ('Paris', 'Lisbon', 44.95, -93.094)]
```

Expected result (New pairs are created):

```
 my_cities = [("Michigan", "Rome", 39.161921, -84.86311),
                ("London", "Lisbon", 38.197274, -93.094),
                ("Paris", "Denver", 44.95, -75.526755)]
```

Comment: What is your expected result.  Also, your `return my_cities` looks like it needs to be unindented one level.

Comment: Show in your post the result you want to get ...

Comment: Just updated my question @codrelphi

Comment: Why Michigan is not with Lisbon like `("Michigan", "Lisbon", 39.161921, -93.094)` ? What is the *reason* of your swapping ?

Comment: I mean, what is the *order* of your swapping or the swapping is done randomly ?

Comment: Yes - are you trying to randomly shuffle them around, or is there some logic to it? Either way, you need to clarify the question.

Comment: by swapping I meant swapping them randomly, together with the coordinate that belongs to the city. Solved it with the belov solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alexander stated in his comment, your return statement is indented too far and inside the for loop. Because of this, only one iteration will occur. Your loop currently sets the value of the current index to whatever the first element of the NEXT index is, twice (as a tuple).

This is why you see `("Michigan", "Michigan")` as the first element of your list at the end.

It is also unclear how you want to swap cities, but it *looks* like you want to rotate them. Ie, if you have:

```
city1A --> city1B
city2A --> city2B
city3A --> city3B
```

then after switching they will all move down one, cyclically:

```
city1A --> city3B
city2A --> city1B
city3A --> city2B
```

Because you always need knowledge of the original cities, you can't directly overwrite them and you'll need some kind of "buffer" to hold onto one city, or all of the original cities. There are two examples below. One leaves the original list alone and doesn't change any of the values while the other one changes the input list *in place*. It's up to you to decide if that's what you want.

```py
my_cities = [("London", "Rome", 38.197274, -84.86311),
                ("Michigan", "Denver", 39.161921, -75.526755),
                ("Paris", "Lisbon", 44.95, -93.094)]

def swap_cities(cities):
    """ 
    Rotates the 2nd city and 2nd location through the list. Does not modify
    cities.

    Input:
        cities: [(str, str, float, float), ...] - The list of city pair tuples

    Returns: A list of new city pairs where the 2nd city and 2nd loc have been
    swapped.
    """
    return [(cities[x][0], cities[x-1][1], cities[x][2], cities[x-1][3]) for x in range(len(cities))]

def swap_cities_inplace(cities):
    """
    Modifies the input list in place to rotate the 2nd city and location through
    the list of city pairs. Explicitly returns None to remind you that this
    modification is IN PLACE.

    Input:
        cities: [(str, str, float, float), ...] - The list of city pair tuples

    Returns: None, but modifies cities in place.
    """
    temp = [(cities[x][0], cities[x-1][1], cities[x][2], cities[x-1][3]) for x in range(len(cities))]
    for i in range(len(cities)):
        cities[i] = temp[i]
    return None

print("Original cities")
print(my_cities)

print("\nSwap cities, not in place")
print(swap_cities(my_cities))
print(f"And see my_cities is unchanged:\n{my_cities}")


print("\nSwap cities in place. This is what my_cities looks like after")
swap_cities_inplace(my_cities)
print(my_cities)
```

Output:

```
Original cities
[('London', 'Rome', 38.197274, -84.86311), ('Michigan', 'Denver', 39.161921, -75.526755), ('Paris', 'Lisbon', 44.95, -93.094)]

Swap cities, not in place
[('London', 'Lisbon', 38.197274, -93.094), ('Michigan', 'Rome', 39.161921, -84.86311), ('Paris', 'Denver', 44.95, -75.526755)]
And see my_cities is unchanged:
[('London', 'Rome', 38.197274, -84.86311), ('Michigan', 'Denver', 39.161921, -75.526755), ('Paris', 'Lisbon', 44.95, -93.094)]

Swap cities in place. This is what my_cities looks like after
[('London', 'Lisbon', 38.197274, -93.094), ('Michigan', 'Rome', 39.161921, -84.86311), ('Paris', 'Denver', 44.95, -75.526755)]
```

So there may be an intimidating looking for-loop comprehension in there. Let's break it down. In both functions, the comprehension is

```
[(my_cities[x][0], my_cities[x-1][1], my_cities[x][2], my_cities[x-1][3]) for x in range(len(my_cities))]
```

The first element is the same city -- remember that we aren't changing this. The second element is the second element of the *previous* entry. This is the city that we swapped with. The third element is the same location for the first city. The fourth element is the location of the *previous* entry's second city. Then, we just use `x` to loop over all the indices of the original list.